# Java UDP broadcast packet cannot be detected

Tags: java, udp, broadcast

I am new to network programming. I want to write a demo program to learn how to send UDP broadcast packets. Here is the small demo I wrote:

```
public class DatagramClient
{
   private final static int PACKETSIZE = 100 ;

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {

      DatagramSocket socket = null ;

      try
      {
         // Convert the arguments first, to ensure that they are valid
         InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName( "67.194.218.255" ) ;
         int port         = 34567;//Integer.parseInt( args[1] ) ;

         // Construct the socket
         socket = new DatagramSocket() ;

         // Construct the datagram packet
         byte [] data = "Hello Server".getBytes() ;
         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, host, port ) ;

         // Send it
         socket.send( packet ) ;

         // Set a receive timeout, 2000 milliseconds
         socket.setSoTimeout( 2000 ) ;

         // Prepare the packet for receive
         packet.setData( new byte[PACKETSIZE] ) ;

         // Wait for a response from the server
         socket.receive( packet ) ;

         // Print the response
         System.out.println( new String(packet.getData()) ) ;

      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
         System.out.println( e ) ;
      }
      finally
      {
         if( socket != null )
            socket.close() ;
      }
   }
}



public class DatagramServer
{

   private final static int PACKETSIZE = 100 ;

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      try
      {

         // Convert the argument to ensure that is it valid

         int port = 34567;

         // Construct the socket
         DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( port ) ;
         socket.setBroadcast(true);

         System.out.println( "The server is ready..." ) ;


         for( ;; )
         {
            // Create a packet
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE ) ;

            // Receive a packet (blocking)
            socket.receive( packet ) ;

            // Print the packet
            System.out.println( packet.getAddress() + " " + packet.getPort() + ": " + new String(packet.getData()) ) ;

            // Return the packet to the sender
            socket.send( packet ) ;
        }  
     }
     catch( Exception e )
     {
        System.out.println( e ) ;
     }
  }
}
```

There is no packets detected by Wireshark but I could not figure out where was wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no broadcasting here. Are the client and server running in the same host?

Comment: what is going wrong? when i run your test, the server receives the test-packet just fine and sends them back to the client. maybe your wireshark is listening on the wrong interface?

Comment: @EJP `67.194.218.255` is a broadcast address

Comment: @umlaeute I ran them in different hosts. Maybe I use the wrong broadcast address. I searched online and it seems that Windows7 now does not support 255.255.255.255 as broadcast address. Can you tell me how you get your broadcast address?

Comment: check your network settings: IPaddress+netmask should give you enough information to calculate the broadcast address. an online [ipcalc](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) might be of help here.

Comment: so i added the answer as a proper "answer", so you can accept and upvote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

your destination address `67.194.218.255` is a broadcast address for the `67.194.218/24` network, but your actual network settings are probably different, so yo have to use the correct broadcast address.

the simplest solution is to use the widest possible broadcast address `255.255.255.255`

if this doesn't work, you might want to narrow down the destination address to your actual network. using your IP-address and your netmask should allow you to calculate the broadcast address by ORing the IP-address with the inverted netmask: e.g. `IP=192.168.1.7; mask=255.255.255.0` -> `broadcast = 192.168.1.7 || 0.0.0.255 = 192.168.1.255`.

for simplicity, you can also use `ipcalc` (a network calculator); there's even an [online version](http://jodies.de/ipcalc).